# Update multiple rows with one value and divide it to the different row in single SQL query

Tags: php, sql

Basically I have two tables itemTable and stockTable, every time I add a stock, I will get the foreign key for itemId and add it in stockTable with quantity.

I want to update the stockquantity in stockTable  every time the customer will buy a product.

PROBLEM:
For example the customer will buy 7 shirt:
SO FIRST WILL UPDATE ON THE STOCKID (3) QUANTITY OF 4
SECOND WILL UPDATE THE STOCKID (6) QUANTITY OF 3

SO THE TOTAL STOCKS OF SHIRT IS 3 AFTER UPDATING THE QUANTITY

THE STOCKID (3) WILL BECOME 0
THE STOCKID (6) WILL BECOME 3

HOW DO I QUERY THAT IN SQL.
THANK YOU!

```
TOTAL STOCKS: (Base on the same itemName)
SHOES - 5
SHIRT - 10
BALL  - 15
```

---

```
stockTable

stockId   itemId    stockQuantity  stockOut
1           35             5
3           89             4 
6           11             6
14          87             15
```

---

```
itemTable

itemId    itemName     itemSellPrice  supplierName
35           shoes          50          Jason
89           shirt          40          Jacob
11           shirt          65          Max
87           ball           150         Sam
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question by editing it. And what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: ....additionally, are you sure that this table and your query belong to the same task? The query uses the columns `stock_quantity` and `item_name` which are both not provided by the given table, neither is the "Generic Name 2" present in that sample data

Comment: Sir I update my questions above, can you please help me, or can you suggest a solution what im going to do in sql i want single query, it's right that im going to loop the order quantity first and update it in the different table, or im gonna use BEGIN, CASE in SQL?

Comment: Because later on I want to trace the quantity of each different supplier.

Comment: Im so sorry sir if im not really good in english.

Comment: you have added PHP as a tag. Do you need pure SQL solution or mixed PHP/SQL approach?

Comment: How would you even know which of each shirt he bought? Is shirt one item but tied back to different suppliers?

Comment: What I mean is, if they buy 7 shirts, how do you know to sell all of your stockId (3) inventory before selling any of the stockId (6) inventory? Why can't I sell all of the stockId (6) and have stockId (3) quantity go down to 3?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify the itemId(s) that must be updated, they are in the result of:

```
SELECT itemId FROM itemTable WHERE itemName = 'shirt'
```

Having said that the update query will look like this:

```
UPDATE stockTable SET ... WHERE itemId IN (SELECT itemId FROM itemTable WHERE itemName = 'shirt')
```

Obviously now we need to update the quantities, this must be done progressively until the order is complete starting from the lowerst itemId (for istance):

```
SELECT IF(stockQuantity>7,@remaining_qty:=stockQuantity-7,@remaining_qty:=@remaining_qty-stockQuantity) AS `remaining_qty` FROM stockTable WHERE itemId IN (SELECT MIN(itemId) FROM itemTable WHERE itemName = 'shirt';

UPDATE stockTable SET stockQuantity=IF(stockQuantity>7,stockQuantity-7,0) WHERE itemId IN (SELECT MIN(itemId) FROM itemTable WHERE itemName = 'shirt');
```

After that you can check the variable @remaining_qty, and reapeat the stuff until  @remaining_qty>0.

Comment: Thank You! Sir it's possible that we will loop all the itemCode in this query, not the MIN of itemCode.